# Как перетащить файл laravel из одной папки в другую

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно перетащить файл из одной папки в другую, и обрезать ее по заданным размерам(crop). Подскажите, как это реализовать в laravel? То в Image что-то не могу найти подходящих методов

Answer (score 1):

Пользуйтесь документацией и готовыми методами. Для работами с файлами используйте "[File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem)". В файле `config/filesystems.php` можно назначать свои хранилища. И тогда не нужно будет возиться с `public_path()` и другой ерундой.

Тогда перемещение файла - плёвое дело.

```
Storage::move('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');
```

Лучше погрузиться в изучение на пару часов, чем потом городить бог весть знает что.

Что касается изменения размера, то в документации [всё есть](http://image.intervention.io/api/crop).

**upd.**
Вообще рекомендую посмотреть [вот сюда](http://image.intervention.io/use/url). Вам не нужно делать самому какие-то обрезания под разные размеры, хранить кучу вариантов одной и той же фотографии и т.п. Вы сохраняете оригинал. Навастриваете свои шаблоны. И даёте ссылку на фотографию, как указано в инструкции. Всё автоматически будет обрезано, уменьшено и всё что захотите, а после сохранено в кеш.

Comment: дорогой а после етого не надо  удолить old/file.jpg??

Comment: @Aram77778 стесняюсь спросить, а зачем? `Storage::move` - перемещает файл, а не копирует. Вы бы хоть почитали, попробовали сначала.

Comment: я не использовал Storage::move вот поетому и спрошиваю но если тебе сложно ответить то мог бы не отвечать google  с радостью ответит

Comment: @Aram77778 так я ответил - метод перемещает файл, а не копирует. Перемещение само по себе подразумевает, что мы берём в одном месте и кладём это в другое место.

Comment: вот спасибо за ответ очень благодарень :)

Comment: одно + от меня:)

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( $user->username != Input::get('username')){

                $new_path =  public_path().'/img/logo/'. Input::get('username').'/'.$user->logo_path;
                $old_path =  public_path().'/img/logo/'. $user->username.'/'.$user->logo_path;
              $move = File::move($old_path, $new_path);
                $delete   =  File::delete($old_path);
            }
```